# Find the determinant of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

Let A be a 3 × 3 real matrix with zero diagonal entries. If $1 + i$ is an eigenvalue of A, the determinant of $A$ equals-

I know the trace of the matrix is sum of eigen value but couldn't solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "zero diagonal entries"? All zeros on the main diagonal?

Comment: Hint: If $1+i$ is an eigenvalue, then so is $1-i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the entries are real, then $i + 1$ can only arise as the root of a polynomial with real coefficients. Such roots appear as conjugate pairs. So you know what 2 of the roots are. The last one is such as to make their sum equal to the trace.

This should be sufficient for you to be able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $i+1$ is an eigenvalue, as already noticed by @PrimeMover and @Bungo, $1-i$ is also an eigenvalue. Then, we know that the trace, which is $0$, is equal to the sum of eigenvalues. Thus:
$$ 2+ \lambda_3 = 0 $$
Therefore, the other eigenvalue is $-2$. Now recall that:
$$ \det A= \prod_{i=1}^{3} \lambda_i = -2(1+i)(1-i)= -4 $$